# How to convert string into two properties inside an array?

Tags: javascript, angular5

Here I am doing to convert the array into required format.       output of parsedValues is ["abcdefgh(4034343), Mikhail(900002)"]
     and Iam trying to convert it as ["abcdefgh(4034343)","Mikhail(900002)"]

How can I convert ["abcdefgh(4034343), Mikhail(900002)"] to ["abcdefgh(4034343)","Mikhail(900002)"] ?

```
private transformUser(userIdsString: any): string[] {
  const parsedUserIdsArray = userIdsString;
  console.log(parsedUserIdsArray);
  const parsedValues = parsedUserIdsArray[4].userids;
  console.log(parsedValues);
  const splitValues = parsedValues.split(',');
  console.log(splitValues);
  const trimmedValues = splitValues.map(str => str.trim());
  console.log(trimmedValues);
  return trimmedValues;
}

The console.log(trimmedValues) is 

(2) ["["abcdefgh(4034343)", "Mikhail(900002)"]"]
0: "["abcdefgh(4034343)"
1: "Mikhail(900002)"]"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Expected is :
    (2) ["abcdefgh(4034343)", "Mikhail(900002)"]
    0: "abcdefgh(4034343)"
    1: "Mikhail(900002)"
    length: 2
    **proto**: Array(0)

Comment: your questions is not clear.(at least for me) try to explain it abit more and show what your trying to convert.

Comment: @Talg123 How can I convert ["abcdefgh(4034343), Mikhail(900002)"] to ["abcdefgh(4034343)","Mikhail(900002)"] ?

Comment: your trying to convet String that looks like this? or is array?

Comment: @Talg123  I am having object ["abcdefgh(4034343), Mikhail(900002)"]

The end output I am trying to convert is array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` on the string, to get an array from a separator (`,` in this case). If you have only one joined string, you can do...

```
["abcdefgh(4034343), Mikhail(900002), Someone(12934)"][0].split(', ')
```

To obtain a new array.

If the original array has multiple strings, you'll need to join all the arrays...

```
["abcdefgh(4034343), Mikhail(900002)", "Someone(12934)"]
.map(item => item.split(', '))
.reduce( (acc, item) => [...acc, ...item], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var input = ["abcdefgh(4034343), Mikhail(900002)"]

input.reduce(function(o,i){
    var values = i.split(',');
    if(values.length > 0){
        o = o.concat(values);
    }return o;},[]);

Output - ["abcdefgh(4034343)", " Mikhail(900002)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const trimmedValues = parsedValues[0].split(', ');
```